# Add Content To DOM AFTER AngularJS Has Completed Asynchronous Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I have angular code that fetches 8 json files asynchronously each via `$http.get`. This is called using `ng-init="someFunct()"` in a template code that is attached. Everything works great including filtering when a user types into an input text box. Filtering is especially important to my application.

To make filtering even better, I extract keywords from the said json files which I then wrap with `<span class="tag" ng-click="filterWith='kywd'">{{kywd}}</span>` in the hope that a user can click on the tags instead of type. This ONLY works if I embed the tags statically - in the real application I cannot know the keywords in advance. If I insert dynamically via `$("#someContainerID").append(TAG_HTML_CODE)` or similar it NEVER works!

In a nutshell this is what I need to achieve:

1) Dynamically inject multiple (in hundreds) such tags into DOM;

2) Inject the tags ONLY after everything else has loaded and compiled - but especially after the json files have been read and keywords extracted;

3) The tags that I inject need to respond to something like `ng-click="filterWith='some_keyword'"`

If there was a way to tell when AngularJS has finished all other processing - how great this would be! I have read everywhere and it seems so cryptic and confusing - pls HELP!

I have even tried the following code to no avail:

```
$timeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {

            //code that works on the keywords - works perfect!

            var filterRegex = /\s*([\w\d.%]+)\s*/i;
            var dom_elem = angular.element(document.querySelector("#filter_tags"));
            dom_elem.html("");
            for (var m = 0; m < tags.length; m += 1) {
                var match = filterRegex.exec(tags[m][0]);
                if (match != null) {
                    dom_elem.append($compile("<span data-ng-model=\"filterWith\" data-ng-click=\"filterWith='" + match[1] + "'\" title=\"" + tags[m][1] + "\" class=\"sk3tag clk\">" + match[1] + "</span>")($scope));
                }
            }
        });
    }, 10000, false);
}
```

**EDIT: Narrowed the scope of my challenge to mainly one!**

The bigger challenge for me is how to enable `ng-click` in the dynamically injected code and how to do it right.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to trigger when everything is loaded.

Comment: OK. I'll try it but it seems that will only address the question of knowing when the file(s) is downloaded? My bigger challenge is how to enable `ng-click` in the dynamically injected code.

Comment: @user3607612 you should really learn about angular directives instead of manually manipulating DOM https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I had asked the question above. Somebody suggested I read further on directives instead. I did, fairly well. I came up with the following solution, to use click events on html code injected dynamically to DOM. I thank truly God for helping me figure it out, eventually. I no longer need to wait for the asynch data, whenever it comes and hence updates the model, my html tags are updated automatically - MVC magic! It seems to work great!

**ANGULAR**
//excerpt

```
myNgApp.controller('ctlTodayLatest', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$compile', '$http', function () {
    $http.get('/filtertags.json').then(function (response) {
            $scope.filterTags = response;
        },
        function (response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
}]);

myNgApp.directive("myFilterTag", function () {
    return {
        template: "<span data-ng-repeat=\"tag in filterTags\" title=\"{{tag[0]}}\" class=\"mytag clk\" ng-click=\"filterWith(tag[0])\">{{tag[0]}}</span>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.filterWith = function (term) {
                scope.fQ = term;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**
//excerpt

```
<div id="filter_tags" class="xip2 TAj" my-filter-tag></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @НЛО for your suggestion to learn about angular directives. Bless you!